# Disable ads in applications?

Tags: ads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to block ads in Android applications?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14249/is-it-possible-to-block-ads-in-android-applications)

Is there a way to disable in-app ads (on a rooted CM7 phone)?

I am NOT talking about the ads in browser.
Blocking ads is legal where I live.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the question [Is it possible to block ads in Android applications?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/14249) already covers this. There are some ad-blocking apps available on the market, but they usually require root-access on the divice -- a condition you meet, as you state in your question. So you may want to take a look at:

- [AdAway](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.adaway)
- [AD Blocker & Data Toggle Trial](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.xdevelop.adblocker_t)
- [Ad Detector Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lite.ad.blocker)
- [AdFree Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bigtincan.android.adfree)
- [AndGuard for Root](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=soapbox.sym3try.andguard)

Just to mention a few examples. Another good option is to buy the app (if there is a payable version), to honour the developers work; he also needs to make a living.