# What is the most effective way to disable ads in an Android app?

Tags: ads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to block ads in Android applications?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14249/is-it-possible-to-block-ads-in-android-applications)

I've read ways but they don't block/disable ads.

Comment: Buy the full version without ads, or write your own program. You can checkout easily how the existing app works (unless it was built with the NDK).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Free applications usually come with ads, since they are used by the developer to [monetize its work](http://developer.android.com/training/monetization/ads-and-ux.html):

> Advertising is one of the means to monetize (make money with) mobile applications.

## Two methods to disable ads:

1. Unrooted device:

   Buy the donate version

   It's getting common among developers to have two versions of their application, one free filled with ads, and one "donate" version where you pay a extra-small-amount and get rid of the ads while helping the developer.

   Additionally, there are other forms of donate to help the developer and get rid of the ads, since they vary alot, best is to read the application summary.
2. Rooted phones:

   There are several applications available from Google Play Store with the sole purpose of blocking ads from the device and applications.

   Essentially, they nullifying requests to known host names in the system hosts file.

   [AdFree Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bigtincan.android.adfree) by BigTinCan.com is amazing for this end.

   [image]

<sup>Personally I don't like the idea of blocking ads since we are essentially preventing developers from earning their day-to-day bread.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You must be rooted for this. If you are rooted, use either of ways:

- Point ad servers to localhost using [Host file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) manually. Sniffing ad servers & adding them to Host file is tedious task.
- Use Ad Blocker apps. There are many Ad Blocker apps available in Play Store viz. [AdFree Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bigtincan.android.adfree), [AdAway](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.adaway) etc. Its easiest, fastest and most effective way.

Comment: Google is starting to remove ad blocker apps. http://www.droid-life.com/2013/03/13/google-begins-removing-ad-blocker-apps-from-google-play/

Comment: @AlEverett Sideloading from other sources is always an option...