# How to remove ads from all apps via a single payment

Tags: ads

I've heard it is possible to pay a subscription service to remove all ads from all apps on your Android phone.

Can someone please tell me how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Related: [How to block ads in Android applications?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/14249/39930)

Comment: Hi Joselin. Could you ask the person (from whom you heard about this service) for more information regarding the said service? Ideally, a web link to the service would be best. For all we know, a person can post an on-topic looking spam post to this question and can easily justify the spam post as a genuine answer. // Also, could you also tell us why the existing solutions on the duplicate post linked in your question are not working out for you? Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily all apps, but **[Google Play Pass](https://play.google/play-pass/) is a monthly subscription service that promises to remove ads on participating apps and games.**

> Your pass to hundreds of awesome games and apps, completely free of ads and in-app purchases. All for one low monthly price.

More information on [Google Play Help - Subscribe to Google Play Pass](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/9473027).

> When you subscribe to Google Play Pass, you’ll get over 1,000 games and apps, without ads or in-app purchases. [...]. Play Pass won’t give you access to all of Google Play, just a selection of apps and games. Availability of games, apps, and offers on Play may vary by country.

Main requirements:

> To buy a subscription to Google Play Pass, you’ll need to:
>
> - Use a device with [Android version 4.4 and above](https://support.google.com/android/answer/7680439).
> - Have Google Play Store app version 16.6.25 and above.
> - Be located in a [country where Play Pass is available](https://support.google.com/googleplay).
> - Have [a valid payment method](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/4646404).
> - Have the same billing country and [Google Play country](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7431675).
> - Use a Google account. You can't subscribe to Play Pass with an account set up through your work or school.
> - [...]